# tool to make /var/report errors readable

Tags: magento2, error

Just what the subject says. Is there anything to reformat the /var/report errors to be more readable? Strip the slashes, replace the new lines?

I've been dicking with the damn thing all morning and can't seem to fully get the

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your issue. Can you please share an error file from ` /var/report`,we can understand the issue

Comment: I don't know of any existing tool really. I tend to just copy them into an editor and make the necessary replacements there. It's so far and in between that it's needed that I can't imagine anyone building a tool for it to be honest.

Comment: @scott, please check my answer.

Comment: @AmitBera \\\\ \n \/ \' all throughout the file in a single line that breaks based on page width. I usually have to end up doing what Rian suggested every time which seemed a tad redundant. Thus is why I wondered if any already built something to reformat it.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, I don't think that there is any tool to beautify report errors.

If you want to see report errors in a better-rendered format (**in the browser**), then you need to:

- Go to /pub/errors folder
- Rename **local.xml.sample** to **local.xml**
- Refresh the website in the browser.

If you don't want to see the error in the browser and instead see the errors in the files under /var/report folder, then:

**Note:** I assume that you are aware of NetBeans editor. If not, the steps mentioned below may vary based on the editor you use to see the files.

- Open the error file in NetBeans editor.
- Press **CTRL + H**, and find all occurrences of "**/**" and replace it with "**/**".
- Press **CTRL + H** again, and find all occurrences of "**\**" and replace it with "****".
- Press **CTRL + H** again. This time, click on **Regular Expression** button also. Now, find all occurrences of "**#**" and replace it with "**\n#**".

You will get a properly rendered report file now.

Please let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: I'm just trying to view them from the shell.